# Spring data and mongoDB - aggregation with java list

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, aggregation-framework, spring-mongodb

I have the following document (@Document):

```
@Id
private String id;
private String fileName;
private String projectId;
private List<DocumentFileVersion> documentFileVersions;
private List<String> userIdBlackList; // here userIds are included
```

and this is my current aggregation:

```
final String userId = "5589929b887dc1fdb501cdbb";
final Aggregation aggregate = newAggregation(match(Criteria.where("projectId").in(projectId)),
        group("fileName").count().as("amountOfDocumentFiles"));
    final AggregationResults<DocumentFileAmount> groupDocumentFiles = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregate, DocumentFile.class,
        DocumentFileAmount.class);
    final List<DocumentFileAmount> documentFileAmounts = groupDocumentFiles.getMappedResults();
    final int amountOfDocumentFiles = documentFileAmounts.size();
```

Now I will extend the aggreagation in that way that I only will have the DocumentFiles where userId (in this case "1234") is not in **userIdBlackList**.
Is there a possibility to do that, like in pseudocode:

```
final Aggregation aggregate = newAggregation(match(Criteria.where("projectId").in(projectId).and(userId).notInList("userIdBlackList")),
    group("fileName").count().as("amountOfDocumentFiles"));
```

I would need something like this: **... .and(userId).notInList("userIdBlackList") ...**

**[EDIT]**
I have tried this query:

```
final Aggregation aggregate = newAggregation(
        match(Criteria.where("projectId").in(projectId).and(userId).and("‌​userIdBlackList").ne(userId)),
        group("fileName").count().as("amountOfDocumentFiles"));
```

A Database entry can look like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("587e7cabafdaff28743f3034"),
"_class" : "com.smartinnotec.legalprojectmanagement.dao.domain.DocumentFile",
"fileName" : "Hydrangeas.jpg",
"projectId" : "587e7c95afdaff28743f302e",
"userIdBlackList" : [
    "5589929b887dc1fdb501cdbb"
    ]
}
```

but **.and(userId).and("‌​userIdBlackList").ne(userId)** has no effect.

**[EDIT2]**

I have tried to simulate it in the mongo console too. 
I have listed all documentfiles with the command **db.DocumentFile.find().pretty()**:

```
db.DocumentFile.find().pretty()
{
"_id" : ObjectId("587f0d61473c92b933a68efa"),
"_class" :   "com.smartinnotec.legalprojectmanagement.dao.domain.DocumentFile",
"fileName" : "DocumentFile1",
"ending" : "jpg",
"projectId" : "587f0d61473c92b933a68ef9",
"active" : true,
"userIdBlackList" : [
    "587f0d61473c92b933a68ef8"
]}
```

and my query looks like this:

```
db.DocumentFile.aggregate({ "$match" : { "projectId" : { "$in" : [ "587f0d61473c92b933a68ef9"]} , "‌​userIdBlackList" : { "$ne" : "587f0d61473c92b933a68ef8"}}}).pretty();
{
"_id" : ObjectId("587f0d61473c92b933a68efa"),
"_class" : "com.smartinnotec.legalprojectmanagement.dao.domain.DocumentFile",
"fileName" : "DocumentFile1",
"ending" : "jpg",
"projectId" : "587f0d61473c92b933a68ef9",
"active" : true,
"userIdBlackList" : [
    "587f0d61473c92b933a68ef8"
]}
```

I have expected that I do not get a documentfile because of this expression **"‌​userIdBlackList" : { "$ne" : "587f0d61473c92b933a68ef8"}**
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

**[EDIT3]**

I have this two documents and with the aggegate:

```
final Aggregation aggregate = newAggregation(
            match(Criteria.where("projectId").in(projectId).and("‌​userIdBlackList").nin(userId)),
            group("fileName").count().as("amountOfDocumentFiles"));
```

I get the amount of 2 but it should 1. I don't know what I am doing wrong?

```
db.DocumentFile.find().pretty()
{
"_id" : ObjectId("587f2228e232342f74b166f9"),
"_class" : "com.smartinnotec.legalprojectmanagement.dao.domain.DocumentFile",
"fileName" : "DocumentFile1",
"ending" : "jpg",
"projectId" : "587f2228e232342f74b166f8",
"active" : true,
"userIdBlackList" : [
    "587f2228e232342f74b166f7"
]}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("587f2228e232342f74b166fa"),
"_class" : "com.smartinnotec.legalprojectmanagement.dao.domain.DocumentFile",
"fileName" : "DocumentFile2",
"ending" : "jpg",
"projectId" : "587f2228e232342f74b166f8",
"active" : true,
"userIdBlackList" : [ ]
}
```

Comment: Did you try `$ne` as `newAggregation(match(Criteria.where("projectId").in(projectId).and(userId).and("userIdBlackList").ne(userId)),...`?

Comment: sry, it does not work

Comment: I think  `and(userId).and("‌​userIdBlackList").ne(userId))` should be `and("‌​userIdBlackList").ne(userId))`

Comment: it still not works

Comment: are you sure ? I ran this generated query from aggregation `db.collection.aggregate({ "$match" : { "projectId" : { "$in" : [ "587e7c95afdaff28743f302e"]} , "‌​userIdBlackList" : { "$ne" : "somestring"}}} , { "$group" : { "_id" : "$fileName" , "amountOfDocumentFiles" : { "$sum" : 1}}});` it returns `{ "_id" : "Hydrangeas.jpg", "amountOfDocumentFiles" : 1 }`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `.nin`

```
final Aggregation aggregate = newAggregation(
                match(Criteria.where("projectId").in(projectId).and("‌​userIdBlackList").nin(userId)),
                group("fileName").count().as("amountOfDocumentFiles"));
```